# Receiving notification sound only when I disable notification from setting

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I have an application that receive notification from firebase console also from php, but I have a problem, that when I disabled notification from settings , then I still receive only sound of notification. I found the code that causes this: I add a two lines of code to receive the notification when the app is open(inforeground) it works and I received notification when app is in foreground and I need it in my app. But it causes the problem I mentioned above, so can any one help me to make app receive notification when its open and without causing this problem?

Here's the code I add in the MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
```

And here is the complete code of MyFirebaseMessagingService (by the way I am sending the notification from php)

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());





    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        //added code(1) by me to try receiving the notification when App in open:




        //end Code(1)
        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);




            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // added code(2) trying receive notification when app is open
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);





            //end (code(2)


            // play notification sound
            //NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
           // notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


 // Showing notification with text only

private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}


// Showing notification with text and image

private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**1.** When your app is in `foreground` state, below lines of codes will be executed:

```
// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

To `disable` notification sound, update `handleNotification()` method as below:

```
private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

    }
}
```

**2.** When your app is in `background` state, below lines of codes will be executed:

```
// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        handleDataMessage(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To `disable` notification sound, remove below lines from `handleDataMessage()` method:

```
// play notification sound
NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
```

**FYI,** If you are managing `notification` settings from your app, then use the respective `preference key` to get the `value` of `notification settings` and add `condition` to `play` notification sound.

Hope this will help~

Comment: i updated handleNotification() also the handle handleDataMessage() as  you mentioned and i still hear the notification sound when notifications are disabled from phone settings (i am hearing the the sound in both when the app is open and close) !!

Comment: i am disabling the notifications from settings of the phone not from my app